# Short story with a boy who goes through a door that isn't there

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

I'm trying to remember a short story I read in the early/mid 80s with some kids who decide to take revenge on a bully, they turn up to his birthday party laden with presents which turn out to be empty; maybe they also try to scare him by putting their clothes on back to front and walking towards him backwards, though that doesn't sound very scary - anyway it ends inside an old empty warehouse or factory with him escaping through a door which then disappears, one of the other kids wonders where you go if you go through a door that isn't there.